# Variable variables named after constants

Tags: php, constants, variable-variables

I have the following class:

```
class ClassFoo {

const MY_CONSTANT = "bar";

function __construct() {

    $my_object = new stdClass;

    // This does not work
    $my_object->$ClassFoo::MY_CONSTANT = "foo";

    }

}
```

I am trying to create a variable of the object `$my_object` to have a name equal to the constant I've defined (`ClassFoo::MY_CONSTANT`).
The following does not work:

```
$my_object->$ClassFoo::MY_CONSTANT = "foo";
```

Nor does this:

```
$my_object->$constant("ClassFoo::MY_CONSTANT") = "foo";
```

There must be a simple solution to this but I can't seem to find it!

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. Do you want access to the constant from outside of the class?

Comment: Huh, to my great surprise this does not appear to be a duplicate. Well done!

Comment: I end up passing the object elsewhere, but really just want to be able to name a variable of the object after a constant I've defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
class ClassFoo {
    const MY_CONSTANT = "bar";

    function __construct() {
        $this->{ClassFoo::MY_CONSTANT} = "foo";
    }
}

$a = new ClassFoo();
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the constant in a variable and use that variable as property name:

```
$propertyName = ClassFoo::MY_CONSTANT;
$this->$propertyName = 'foo';
```

Comment: So could you please help and explain it, instead of downvoting?

Comment: I don't need to. @Rawkode's accepted answer demonstrates what the OP was after. Your answer demonstrates a related thing that is not quite the same as what was requested in the question.